# What does it mean by the statement "NumPy is a dependency of Pandas"?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

I have read in a blog: "NumPy is a dependency of Pandas", while referring to Pandas' "Series" object. Does it only mean that NumPy ndarray is an object that can be fed into the "data" parameter of the Series constructor?

I have provided NumPy ndarray object as an argument to "data" parameter, and a one-dimensional Series object was the result.

Answer (score 0):

It means that when you install the Pandas module, for example via `pip`, it will also automatically install numpy as well.

Numpy has some low-level code ( [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) and [LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) ). Which normally needs compiling for the target system you're working on, so *sometimes*, depending on your target platform, if binaries aren't freely available, the install process might need access to the compilation toolkit on your machine. If it's already installed, then you've got nothing to worry about.

99 times of out 100 you wont see or be aware of it, but in those rare cases outlined above, you might need to handhold the installation.

Pandas makes use of this low-level numpy code for performance, hence the dependency - it's nothing to do with how you feed it information - though some of the datatypes you might encounter when looking at pandas outputs can lean heavily on established numpy definitions (see NaN and some float-type definitions for example)

If you run

`pip install pandas`

Chances are, it will go and download numpy for your platform, no compilation or other moves required.

Post installation you'll see you've got pandas, and numpy (possibly a couple of other modules as well) installed into your python environment.

In terms of using numpy objects as part of the interface into using pandas, it's certainly not a requirement, so I wouldn't worry about doing that unless there's a specific use-case that requires or supports it. I'd not avoid it either, it's just not something to worry about in that respect.

The [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas-dataframe) constructor accepts all kinds of different inputs in the `data` parameter - from the docs:

> **Parameters**: **data**: ndarray (structured or homogeneous), Iterable, dict, or
> DataFrame
>
> Dict can contain Series, arrays, constants, dataclass or
> list-like objects. If data is a dict, column order follows
> insertion-order. If a dict contains Series which have an index
> defined, it is aligned by its index.

Similarly, in the [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html#pandas-series) constructor:

> **Parameters** : **data** : array-like, Iterable, dict, or scalar value
>
> Contains data stored in Series. If data is a dict, argument
> order is maintained.

In the above, the references to [`ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) or "array-like" objects do include the object type defined and standardised by numpy, along with multiple *iterable* objects (anything that returns multiple sub-objects in a for-each type loop such as lists) or dicts, or other DataFrame objects - so the range of input options is pretty wide.

Both of those constructor links above contain some examples that include non-numpy constructions, and it's worth trying out a few different ways of building your DataFrames/Series until you find a method you're comfortable with - the wide range of options can enable some quite creative and elegant workflows, so I think the best thing to do is experiment.